# Gui and Serializable Errors

Tags: java, swing, serialization, serializable

Ok,so I need to write a program which creates profiles (simple ones with just a name, photo, status etc.) and it adds friends which exist. It saves the profiles in a file using `ObjectOutputStream`. Now the problems I am facing so far are:

- I am getting Serializable Errors and I don't know where they are coming from.
  Errors that the project gives
- java.io.NotSerializableException: SocialNetwork 
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source) at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)

The code is about 250 lines so I am gonna add 3 comments with the error  description where they are happening. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Error Here Guys) is the word

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class SocialNetwork implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 904698037930887085L;
        RandomAccessFile raf ;
        JTextField setStatus ;
        JTextField addFriend ;
        JTextField emriProfilit ;
        JButton changestatus ;
        JButton setfriend ;
        JButton changepicture ;
        JButton add ;
        JButton delete ;
        JButton lookup ;
        JLabel name ;
        JLabel password ;
        JPasswordField passwordfield ;
        JLabel Banner ;
        SocialProfile profile ;
        SocialProfile temp ;
        JLabel profilepicture ;
        FileOutputStream fileoutput;
        FileInputStream fileinput ;
        ObjectOutputStream output;
        ObjectInputStream input;

        public SocialNetwork() throws FileNotFoundException{

        fileoutput = new FileOutputStream("database.dat",true);
        fileinput = new FileInputStream("database.dat");
        emriProfilit = new JTextField(15);
        name = new JLabel("Name");
        password = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordfield = new JPasswordField (7);
        lookup = new JButton("Lookup");
        add = new JButton("Add");
        delete = new JButton("Delete");
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel() ;
        p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p1.add(name);
        p1.add(emriProfilit);
        p1.add(password);
        p1.add(passwordfield);
        p1.add(add);
        p1.add(delete);
        p1.add(lookup);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Social Network");
        frame.setSize(1050,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        changestatus = new JButton ("Change Status");
        setfriend = new JButton ("Add Friend");
        changepicture = new JButton ("Change Picture");
        setStatus = new JTextField (20);
        addFriend = new JTextField (15) ;
        ImageIcon sfond= new ImageIcon("images/socialnetwork.png");
        Banner = new JLabel (sfond);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel() ;
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel() ;
        JPanel p4 = new JPanel() ;
        p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,10,10));
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1,10,10));

        p3.add(Banner);
        p2.add(setStatus);
        p2.add(changestatus);
        p2.add(changepicture);
        p2.add(addFriend);
        p2.add(setfriend);
        p4.add(p3);
        p4.add(p2);
        p4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    // Error here guys (sometimes it does not show )


frame.add(p4,BorderLayout.WEST);
// Veprimi i cili do kryhet mbasi të klikohet butoni changepicture
changepicture.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        File file = browsefile();
        profile.setAvatar(file.getAbsolutePath());
        profilepicture.setIcon(profile.getAvatar());
    }

});
// Veprimi që do realizohet mbasi të jepet emri
    emriProfilit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        profile = new SocialProfile();  
        profile.setName(emriProfilit.getText().trim());
        emriProfilit.setFocusable(false);
    }

    });
    // Veprimi që do realizohet mbasi të jepet password-i
    passwordfield.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            profile.setPassword(passwordfield.getPassword());
            passwordfield.setFocusable(false);
        }

        });
    // Veprimi që do realizohet kur të klikohet butoni changestatus
    changestatus.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            profile.setStatus(changestatus.getText().trim());

        }

        });
    // Veprimi që do kryhet nga butoni add
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            try {
                add(profile);
            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        });
    // Veprimi që do kryhet nga butoni lookup
    lookup.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String name ;   
            name = emriProfilit.getText().trim();
            try {
                if(doesitexist(name))
                    System.out.println("Ekziston");
                else
                    System.out.println("Nuk Ekziston");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            emriProfilit.setFocusable(false);
            passwordfield.setFocusable(false);
        }

        });
}
    // Error here Guys


    public void add(SocialProfile profile) throws IOException{
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(fileoutput);
            output.writeObject(profile);
        }
        //Error here Guys


    public boolean doesitexist(String name) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
            input = new ObjectInputStream(fileinput);

            try{
                while(true){
            temp = (SocialProfile)(input.readObject());
                if (temp.getName().equals(name)){
                    return true ;
                }
                }
            }
            catch (EOFException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return false ;
            }
        }
        public File browsefile(){
            JFileChooser filebrowse = new JFileChooser ();
            if (filebrowse.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

            }
            File file = filebrowse.getSelectedFile();
            return file ;
        }



        public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        new SocialNetwork();
    }
        public class SocialProfile implements Serializable {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 2436758770296955312L;
            /**
             * 
             */

            private String name ;
            private ImageIcon avatar;
            private String status ;
            private ArrayList<String> friends ;
            private char[] password ;



            public SocialProfile(){
                status = new String ("Default Status");
                friends = new ArrayList<String>( );
                avatar = new ImageIcon ("images/defaultavatar.jpg");

            }
            public String getName (){
                return name ;
            }
            public void setName(String name){
                this.name = name ;
            }
            public void setPassword (char[] pass){
                password = pass ;
            }
            String getStatus (){
                return status ;
            }

            void setStatus (String status){
                this.status = status ;
            }

            ImageIcon getAvatar (){
                return avatar ;
            }
            void setAvatar (String avatarpicture){
                avatar = new ImageIcon(avatarpicture) ;
            }
            void addFriend (String name){
                friends.add(name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That downvote......If you don't want to reply or help atleast do not downvote.If you think this question does not have a point,you may report it ,but atleast don't dontvote.Maybe someone can help!!!

Comment: have you closed the file after writing to it? the stream and the file as well needs to be closed.

Comment: Yes I have already done that one.I added transient at all variables of SocialProfile and it still does not work...Strange

Comment: @FerencDajka I think I figured out what was wrong,I declared the SocialProfile as a non inner class and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Class that was serialized shouldn't have been defined as an Inner Class.I declared the class as a new public one and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to serialize the GUI components. Try t serialize the object model and the object model to dynamically load the ui.

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work even while doing that.The only reason I serialized the Class with the GUI Components was because the compiler was giving an error about the Class not being serialized.If you see the code you will understand that I do not write or read the serialized Class with GUI Components.Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the stream after usage, you should always close a file after writing to it.

About the not showing border, you should call frame.setVisible(true) at the end after you've added every component to it, if still not showing you should call repaint() or updateui() methods for the frame, and I suggest to extend your class from the  JFrame class if you use only one frame, this is for easier usage.

About the serialization, I think your code is correct, what are the errors you recive after building the project?

**EDIT :**
I've found this [page](http://craftingjava.blogspot.hu/2012/06/javaionotserializableexception_17.html)  about this problem, seems like you have a non serializeable object in your class, so first of all remove the  `implements Serializable`  part from your SocialNetwork class, and try to find the NotSerializeable object in your SocialProfile class. I'd remove the code parts and start testing it, for example leave the primitive types only, and check that if you are able to serialize that way.

The increasing file size means definetly that something is happening there, try to delete the file before running the Serialization code.

Comment: I did what you said and you where right about the border.The first problem was fixed,I did close the file and stream but it still gives me errors at the console.I should mention that the file gets bigger,like content is being written there.Anyway here are some errors that show ...

Comment: I edited the post and added what you asked.Thanks for fixing the first problem.

Comment: I gave you a +1 for helping me with the panel that was not showing,and I posted an answer for the others who might face this problem.

Comment: I haven't even realized that you made an inner class, I suggest you never do that, always create a new file for any class you define. Your code will be embraceable, and you will find the problems easier. And please accept your own answer if you can (maybe stackoverflow does not allow you yet).

Comment: I can't accept it yet.